# DirectX 9 - Quads becoming stretched when rotated in orthographic view

Tags: rotation, directx, sprite, orthographic

I'm working on some code to render a list of sprites using one large vertex buffer in DirectX 9 as textured quads. I'm having an issue with these textured quads becoming stretched out when rotated and rendered in an orthographic view. The odd thing is that no stretching occurs when rotated 0 or PI radians, and stretching is at its highest when rotated 1/2 PI or 1 1/2 PI radians.

[image]

It seems plausible that this is down to the view or projection matrices, or an issue when generating the rotation matrix, however I have been unable to find any solution after plenty of tweaking and testing. For reference, the texture used is 32x32 pixels.

Here's the code I use initially to set the projection and view matrices for all sprites:

```
D3DXMATRIX projection;
D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH(&projection, -(float)ScreenWidth / 2.0f,
                                         (float)ScreenWidth / 2.0f,
                                         (float)ScreenHeight / 2.0f,
                                        -(float)ScreenHeight / 2.0f,
                                         1.0f, 1000.0f);

HR(mFX->SetMatrix(mProjectionHandle, &projection));

D3DXMATRIX view;
D3DXVECTOR3 pos(0.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
D3DXVECTOR3 up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
D3DXVECTOR3 target(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&view, &pos, &target, &up);

HR(mFX->SetMatrix(mViewHandle, &view));
```

And the code for creating the rotation matrix:

```
D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&_rotation,
                    (2.0f * D3DX_PI) - _spriteComponent.GetRotation());
```

And finally the shader code:

```
outVS.col.a = gAlpha;

outVS.posH = mul(float4(posL, 1.0f), gWorld);
outVS.posH = mul(outVS.posH, gView);
outVS.posH = mul(outVS.posH, gProjection);
outVS.posH = mul(outVS.posH, gScaling);
outVS.posH = mul(outVS.posH, gRotation);
outVS.posH = mul(outVS.posH, gTranslation);

outVS.tex0 = tex0;

return outVS;
```

I have also tried using the D3DXMatrixOrthoLH() function when setting the projection matrix and the same issue occurs. Any ideas what could be causing this odd scaling?

Comment: You create a new rotation matrix each frame, and not mutate the previous one right?

Comment: Yeah the rotation matrix is created in my main rendering function each frame and then a reference is passed to the function which calculates it and passes it to the shader.

Comment: shouldn't view and projection be multiplied last, after the translation?  I'm guessing, but its worth a quick try.

Comment: Will you're an absolute hero. I tried a fair few combinations of matrix multiplication but not that one surprisingly, and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help.